# How to change the language of Google Speech API on Java?

Tags: java, google-speech-api

I am using [Google Speech API on Java](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/tree/master/speech/grpc).

I can find language configuration something like `languagecode` in Python version, but I can't find that in Java version.
I can find documents changing the language for Python, but I can't find for Java. And, I can't find something like `languagecode` or `en_US` in Java source.

How to change the language of Google Speech API on Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a field of the RecognitionConfig object, so you should be able to set it [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/master/speech/grpc/src/main/java/com/examples/cloud/speech/StreamingRecognizeClient.java#L198).

I don't have access to the Java code at the moment, but it's probably something like this:

```
RecognitionConfig config =
      RecognitionConfig.newBuilder()
          .setEncoding(AudioEncoding.LINEAR16)
          .setSampleRate(samplingRate)
          .setLanguageCode("en-US")
          .build();
```

Of course, you can omit the encoding and sample rate if you're using the default values.

This field is part of the API so it may be defined in a protobuf file rather than in Java source files.

Comment: Great!  @dtd if it answers your question, you should go ahead and [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) this answer.